# Can we add node to Selenium Grid over internet using MAC address?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-rc, selenium-grid

Can we add node from one computer to GRID which is running in another computer over internet ?(Using MAC address something like that). Or is there any other way which I can run grid tests over internet remotely.

Answer (score 0):

You have to maintain a hub and a server and run selenium commands through the internet. You need to publish the node ip address and the hub address. If you can ping each other and the hubs are open. Then indeed you can.

Answer (score 0):

You can make it possible by using ngrok(https://ngrok.com/).

1. Start selenium hub and node on the machine where you want to execute your script.
2. Download ngrock from https://ngrok.com/
3. Execute command

> c:\ngrok-stable-windows-amd64> ngrok http 4444

which will generate public URL as below:

```
Session Status  online 
Version 2.2.8 
Region   United States (us) 
Web Interface   http://127.0.0.1:4040 
Forwarding      http://9d17a0b4.ngrok.io -> localhost:4444 
Forwarding      https://9d17a0b4.ngrok.io -> localhost:4444
```

4. In selenium script, initialize remote web driver object as below:

> RemoteWebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new
>   URL("https://9d17a0b4.ngrok.io/wd/hub"), capability);